# Getting the right WebElement in WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have an HTML page that roughly looks like this:

```
<div id="rolesRollerBody" style="height: 309px;">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll('removeRolesForm');" name="allbox">
    Select all
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="49893" name="delRole">
    CCC11
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="49881" name="delRole">
    TEST111
    <br><br>
</div>
```

I am getting the entire panel by using:

```
WebElement deletePanel = driver.findElement(By.className("bulkUpdateBody"))
            .findElement(By.id("rolesRollerBody"));
```

Now I need to get the checkbox with the name 'TEST111'. The problem is, I am not able to get the text 'TEST111'.

Comment: That is some horrible markup. I guess it could be done somehow, but if you have control over the HTML code, it would _far_ easier to markup the page in a proper way and then search easily.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have. I am required to automate few test cases related to this feature without any control over the layout. :(

Comment: I'm going to come up with a solution. On a side note, you can use just `driver.findElement(By.id("rolesRollerBody"))` instead of your `driver.findElement(By.className("bulkUpdateBody")).findElement(By.id("rolesRollerBody"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) solution:

```
id('rolesRollerBody')/text()[contains(.,'TEST111')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

this selects:

> ```
> input                          - The `input` element
> /preceding-sibling::input[1]   - that is most closely followed by
> /text()[contains(.,'TEST111')] - the 'TEST111' text
> id('rolesRollerBody')          - in the element with id 'rolesRollerBody'.
> ```

or, in the direct order:

> ```
> id('rolesRollerBody')          - The element with id 'rolesRollerBody'
> /text()[contains(.,'TEST111')] - in that, the text node containing 'TEST111'
> /preceding-sibling::input[1]   - and the first preceding `input` element to that text
> ```

Therefore,

```
WebElement theInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('rolesRollerBody')/text()[contains(.,'TEST111')]/preceding-sibling::input[1]"));
```